# What is the least expensive way of rendering a static template in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use Knockout for rendering a static template. The template has bindings to the data model. The data models is a plain object without any observables. As far as I know I can use `ko.applyBindings`, `ko.applyBindingsToDecendans`, `ko.renderTemplat`, etc. My question:

- What is the least expensive way of rendering a static template in Knockout?

By being inexpensive I mean avoiding creating unnecessary objects, observables, dependent observables, association of DOM elements with data objects, etc. that might be omitted for a static template.

Comment: If it is really static, just render it server side. It if changes based on client activity, standard ko.applyBindings using a js view model performs just fine.

Comment: sort of found the way: http://jsperf.com/knockout-template-engines/25

Comment: @Peter it is static as soon as it gets rendered. It doesnt make sense to do it on server because all data is on client already

Answer (score 0):

i put together this jsperf to see how much of a difference there was.  Seems pretty substantial in favor of renderTemplate.

http://jsperf.com/template-rendering